# Expectation value and the probability of finding a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, probability, born-rule

I'm trying to understand basic quantum physics, as I understand, the expectation value of some random distribution gives us the outcome that we might expect(highest probability) if the event is done once. So I presume that the expectation value of the probability density function

> $|\Psi|^2$ would give us the region with highest chance where the particle might be found right?

But in this problem - part (c)

[image]

When I sketch the function, I get that at point

> $x = a$, the particle has the maximum value of the probability density function, isn't $x = a$ where the particle is most likely to be found?

But the expectation value $\left\langle x \right\rangle$ is not equal to $a$ (the most likely value). Why are they not equal if the definition of the expectation value of a random distribution is the most likely value (when the experiment is performed once)?
Am I going wrong somewhere? Humbly requesting your help, thanks for taking the time to read through this, I sincerely appreciate your time.

Comment: The expectation value does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: If you roll a (fair) 6-sided die, the expectation value will $21/6$, which is not one of the possible outcomes, so the expectation value *cannot* be the most probable outcome.  Indeed in this case all outcomes are equally probable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence "*the expectation value of some random distribution gives us the outcome that we might expect(highest probability) if the event is done once.*" is false. The expectation value of some random distribution does not contain information (and it should always be one)

$$ \int dx |\psi(x)|^2 = 1$$

It is the expectation value of some operator applied to the have function that gives us the expectation value. In the case of $\left\langle x  \right\rangle$ is
$$ \int dx |\psi(x)|^2x$$

The maximum of a distribution does not need to coincide with the mean. The expectation value is the mean value (in this case the mean position) and not the most likely position. It is the same as the difference between the mean and the mode:https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/summarizing-quantitative-data/mean-median-basics/a/mean-median-and-mode-review.

Answer (score 0):

Expectation value of a dynamical variable means we prepare a set of identical systems (ensemble) and do the measurement and find the results. Then we find out the average of those result. Here we prepare a set of identical system, do position measurement , we average it and find  the expectation value of x.
Now, the maximum value of probability density function says that the particle is most likely to be found there. And if the probability density function do not change with time the particle will always have a greater chance to stay there.
So, the cases are different.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have explained, you are confusing a few definitions in statistics, so I'll try to help.

The reason why the "expectation value of x" (or mean value) isn't necessarily the maximum of the probability is better understood if you take a look at a couple of curves. For example, take these distributions:
[image: distribution]
You can see how each curve has a different maximum, but it is also "twisted" in a way so that it occupies mostly a certain area of the graph, making it so the **values are not evenly distributed around that maximum**. So, it would be fair to say that most people have incomes that are lower than $40k$, because that's where most of the values land.

So even though the maximum is still the **most probable value** (as in, if you take just one measurement, it's the value you expect to get), in multiple extractions, you expect the value to be in the region where the graph of the distribution function shows higher probabilities. Or, in other words, you need to take the **mean** to see where most of your values are. That's what defines the "place where the particle is most probable to be found" and it doesn't have to coincide with the maximum.

Now, you can get that information by using the definition of the mean value and the knowledge you already have of the distribution function:

$$\text{Discrete:} \langle x \rangle = \sum_n x_n p(x_n) $$
$$\text{Continuous:}  \langle x \rangle = \int_{x_0}^{x_f} dx \cdot x  \cdot p(x)$$

Where $x$ represents all the possible values and $p(x)$ their probability.

In quantum mechanics, as you probably have found by now, the probability distribution is described as $p(x) = |\Psi (x)|^2$ (which is why $\int dx |\Psi (x)|^2 = 1 $), so you can either calculate the mean value with the expression above for the continuous distribution or, in the case where you have a function like:

$$\Psi (x,0) = c_1 \phi_1(x,0) + c_2 \phi_2(x,0)$$

where $\phi(x)$ represent **normalized wave functions**, you can just compare the coefficients, since the probability of $x$ being in a state $\phi$ is going to be $|c|^2$, and that will tell you in which state you're most likely to find the particle.

Bit of a long answer, but I hope it clears things up!